# Why QMenu:hover doesnt work in QtDesigner

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

`QMenu:hover` doesn't work in QtDesigner 
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Did you try to make it via .qrc file with .css file?

Comment: @bodyname Sorry? I dont get your point

Comment: You can create qrc file there will be your styles (css) and fonts (otf) and etc... 
Load it via import in python. 

"pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc"
--
"import resources"

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QMenu:selected** should do the trick.

```
QMenu{
    background-color:red;
}

QMenu:selected {
    background-color:black;
}
```

[image]

In alternative you can try this way:

```
QMenu {
    background-color: red;
}


QMenu::item:selected {
    background-color:black;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @mecdeality I've updated the answer, this is what looks like using the two methods, isn't it what you need? When you hover the item with the mouse it applies the backgorund-color:black.